# PHP: get_called_class() vs get_class($this)

Tags: php, oop

In PHP what is the difference between [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) and [`get_class($this)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) when used inside an instance?

Example:

```
class A {
    function dump() {
        echo get_called_class();
        echo get_class($this);
    }
}

class B extends A {}

$A = new A();
$B = new B();

$A->dump(); // output is 'AA'
$B->dump(); // output is 'BB'
```

Is there any difference in this case?

When should I be using one or the other `get_called_class()` or `get_class($this)`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this case there's no difference, because `$this` always points to the correct instance from which the class name is resolved using `get_class()`.

The function `get_called_class()` is intended for static methods. When static methods are overridden, this function will return the class name that provides the context for the current method that's being called.

Answer (score 23):

For much faster alternative of `get_called_class()` in PHP >= 5.5, use `static::class`.  It works to get the top level class for static method calls, as well as for inherited methods.

Answer (score 1):

Not in this case... if dump was a static method and eliminate the `$this` parameter then get_class would return "A" in both cases and get_called_class would return "B" when you did `B::dump();`

Answer (score 0):

In this instance there is no difference, both return the name of the class, but the get_called _class has Late Static Binding

Answer (score 0):

The answer, in this particular case, is : **NO**.

There is no difference.

---

**Reference :** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

> **string get_class ([ object $object = NULL ] )**
>
> ...
>
> If object is omitted when inside a class, the name of that class is returned.