# PHP get current class name in inherited class

Tags: php, oop

I have this code in PHP:

```
abstract class Development
{   
    static function testUnit()
    {
        echo get_class();
    }
}

class Component extends Development
{    
}
```

But if I am calling
Component::testUnit();

I am receiving Development instead of Component. It is puzzling me because such static function has no meaning I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use get_called_class instead ...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Answer (score 3):

As @Jason at FloSports said, you can use get_called_class, with that there is 1 more ways, you can get current called class name and i.e. `echo get_class($this);`

Since, you are already using get_class(), you just have to add $this. So, that it could point current class. Here's an attached [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515516/php-get-called-class-vs-get-classthis) that will help you understand between these 2 functionsSee, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. Jason is right, "get_called_class" was the correct function. But adding $this solves nothing because the method is static.

Comment: True, get_class($this) will not work on static class